# How to match this regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

`url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)$')` matches 1 word with alphanumeric letters like `quark` or `light` or `blade`.

What regex should I use to match patterns like these?

```
quark.express.shift
```

or

```
quark.mega
```

or

```
light.blaze.fist.blade
```

I tried `url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w+]*)$')` , `url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w*)$')` and other combinations but, didnt get it correct.

Comment: You should probably add what you also want to _not_ match, `    ` , `...` or `.light.` (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to include a period, add it in the character class in your first attempt like so:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.]*)$')
                               ^
```

[Note that I also removed the `+` in there as this would cause the regex to match a plus character too]

If you want to keep the same functionality of the first regex, use `+` instead of `*` (to match at least 1 character as opposed to 0 or more):

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.]+)$')
```

Comment: I think you need to use "\." and not just ".", otherwise it'll match any character.

Comment: @dutt You don't need to escape periods when they are in character classes. They become literal characters when inside `[ ... ]`.